# R ggpubr use global environment objects?

Tags: r, environment-variables, ggpubr

I want to use the ggpubr package referring to data frame column names that are listed in character strings in my global environment, but ggpubr doesn't seem to take variables, only hardcoded column names. Is there a way I can make any changes so it can do this?

```
vars = c('var1', 'var2')
controls = c('a', 'w')

df = data.frame(subject = 1:100,
                value = rnorm(100, 100, 10),
                var1 = rep(c('a', 'b'), 50),
                var2 = rep(c('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'), 25))

library(ggpubr)

compare_means(value ~ vars, df, ref.group = 'a')
```

But I want to be able to replace 'vars' with var[1], var[2], etc and same for the ref.group = controls[1], controls[2]. Can I get ggpubr to refer to global environment objects instead of taking the input directly as column names?

Comment: With a formula interface, you could presumably build the formula as a string and use `as.formula` on it. `my_form = as.formula(paste(vars[1], vars[2], sep = "~"))` and then `compare_means(my_form, df, ref.group = 'a')`. Never used `ggpubr` so this is untested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reformulate`

```
library(ggpubr)
fml <- reformulate(vars[1], 'value')
compare_means(fml , df, ref.group = controls[1])
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#  .y.   group1 group2     p p.adj p.format p.signif method  
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 value a      b      0.537  0.54 0.54     ns       Wilcoxon
```

and for multiple elements using corresponding values, use `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) compare_means(reformulate(x, 'value'), df, 
       ref.group = y), vars, controls)
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(vars, controls, ~ compare_means(reformulate(.x, 'value'), df,
            ref.group = .y))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#  .y.   group1 group2     p p.adj p.format p.signif method  
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 value a      b      0.537  0.54 0.54     ns       Wilcoxon

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  .y.   group1 group2     p p.adj p.format p.signif method  
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 value w      x      0.126  0.38 0.13     ns       Wilcoxon
#2 value w      y      0.985  1    0.98     ns       Wilcoxon
#3 value w      z      0.969  1    0.97     ns       Wilcoxon
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I didn't about reformulate. Can you also help apply this need to a ggplot, where it's not the same formula? For instance, getting this to work over the length of vars: ```ggplot(df, aes(vars[1], value))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = vars[1]))```

Comment: @user42485  previously, you could use `aes_string(vars[1], "value")` Now, it can be `aes(!! rlang::sym(vars[1], value)) +`